# Are there any high reward dailies available besides Tol Barad

Tags: world-of-warcraft

After I've cleared Dragon Soul for the week and done all of my jewel crafting and Tol Barad dailies, I still have dailies for the day that are available but I can't seem to find any that are worthwhile. I get a lot of enjoyment out of running Tol Barad dailies and I'm building towards a mount and some enchants. I do my jewel crafting ones daily to get the high end recipes. My question is, what are other worthwhile dailies? You might say worthwhile is subjective depending on what I need so I guess I'll put it this way. I have an ilvl of 392, so I doubt I'll get much in gear. I enjoy collecting mounts/pets. I'm still a noob when it comes to PvP gear. I'm just looking to find some dailies I've never heard of that will reward me with something entertaining.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing.. How is this question not voted up more?? Anyway, I hope most of the answers to this are still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many daily quests one can choose from in a day to reach the 25 quest limit per day.  The rewards from these quests always include gold, but sometimes include other things such as mounts, pets, reputation, gear, achievements, and titles.  As for "worthwhile" dailies, it sounds like that would include any that give you something other than money for you.  You would have to do some research on each individual faction, but most factions have dailies you can complete to grind to exalted (but not all).  Some of these are very similar, if not exactly the same, as Tol Barad dailies.  You do dailies, gain reputation, then you can buy things from their quartermaster through money or other currencies.  Some of the ones that I enjoyed doing, or had a rewarding experience from included the following:

Note: The descriptions are my own; take them with a grain of salt.

**Tol Barad**(lvl 85) - As you mentioned, two mounts, a pet, and various toys.
**Molten Front**(85) -  Pets, toys, lots of achievements, and ultimately a title and mount ("the Flamebreaker" and a Flaming Hippogryph).  This is the long and arduous quest chain that leads the player to the Firelands and explains the situation. Very entertaining and rewarding.
**Argent Tournament**(80) - Each daily rewards you with crusader tokens that you can use to buy a huge number of things including, but not limited to mounts, pets, tabards, and toys. Reputation can be gained toward multiple factions through this chain.  You also receive titles for unlocking each part of the line ("of [city]"), as well as the "Crusader" title upon unlocking every part.  This line is dynamic to a point, but takes a very long time to gather enough tokens to buy all the cool things.
**Netherwing**(70) - Rewards one of my favorite type of flying mounts, was an epic grind back in the day.   Also had very entertaining and challenging racing quests as you increased reputation.
**Shattered Sun Offensive**(70) - The first phased daily quest line.  Was interactive when it was relevant, since new parts of the Sunwell raid weren't unlocked on your server until the players on that server collectively did enough dailies.  Probably boring now.  Rewards a cool tabard and title ("of the Shattered Sun").
**Sha'tari Skyguard**(70) - Not very engaging past the first few days, takes a long time; rewards include nether ray mounts and a multitude of achievements.
**Wintersaber Trainers**(60) - A grind of absolutely epic proportion when it first came out (wasn't in a daily format).  Has since been re-tooled to account for complaints about inaccessibility, and is more of a daily-type experience that doesn't take too long to complete.  Since I did the original version, I'm not entirely sure what it's like now.  Rewards a very sleek looking Wintersaber mount.
**Darkmoon Faire**(any) - A new (refurbished) event that shows up once a month.  Rewards include mounts, pets, and cosmetic armor that doesn't exist anywhere else in the game (anymore).  Earning tickets from this takes a while since it isn't always around.

Each of these reward reputation and an achievement or two.  This is not a complete list of dailies that have good rewards.  There are most certainly others that fit in the same category, but I don't feel like listing every single one.  There are a few that are just a simple daily that is unlocked through main quests that have a chance to drop something cool.  I'll let you discover these, as well as the multitude of other options there are.  It is a role-playing game, after all!

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole suite of dailies in the Firelands that reward multiple pets and flavor items along the way, and a mount at the end. These differ from Tol Barad in that as you do them, you unlock different stages and additional dailies as you go.

To get started, head to the portal area in Orgrimmar/Stormwind. [(Source)](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2743694693)

For more details, check out [Wowhead's guide to Patch 4.2](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=4.2).

In my personal experience, Firelands had the best dailies yet. You unlock additional stages on a personal level and at your own pace, and they are sometimes even a little challenging (well, not really, but still more interesting than the Tol Barad grind). Once you start unlocking the different factions, you can even choose which set of dailies to do so you don't get bored of doing the same thing every day.

Also, you should get used to this "progressive" daily model, as it's been said that Mists of Pandaria will use a similar model.